# I get an error when using `\ExecuteOptions` together with `\usepackage{geometry}`

Tags: document-classes, geometry, options

I'm writing a custom document class. It's kinda simple, but it will use the `geometry` package to set page size, orientation and margins. However... Whenever I use that package, the [`\ExecuteOptions`](http://tex.loria.fr/general/new/clsguide.html#Sec%3acommands.options) command stops working. Look at this minimalist testcase:

File: *myclass.cls*

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClass{article}

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,
    includehead, includefoot,
    headheight=23mm, headsep=5mm, footskip=1.5em]{geometry}

\DeclareOption{landscape}{\geometry{landscape, top=12mm, bottom=12mm, left=15mm, right=15mm}}
\DeclareOption{portrait}{\geometry{portrait, top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=12mm, right=12mm}}
\ExecuteOptions{portrait}
\ProcessOptions
```

File: *doc.tex*

```
% This works: \documentclass{myclass}
% This does not work: \documentclass[foobar]{myclass}
% This does not work: \documentclass[landscape]{myclass}
% This does not work: \documentclass[anythingITypeHere]{myclass}
\documentclass[landscape]{myclass}

\title{Simple testcase}

\begin{document}

Simple experiment... I think it should have worked.

\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ExecuteOptions ...eserved@a \CurrentOption \@nil 

l.19 \ExecuteOptions{portrait}
```

If I don't pass any option to the `\documentclass` command, then it compiles. However, if I try to pass anything (like in the example above), it fails with that weird message.

If I comment out `\usepackage[...]{geometry}`, and replace `\geometry` with something else, then it compiles. So, I'm quite sure this package is messing with `\ExecuteOptions` command.

If I put both `\DeclareOption` and `\ExecuteOptions` before importing the package, I get an error about undefined `\geometry` (as expected).

If I put `\DeclareOption` before the `\usepackage`, and leave `\ExecuteOptions` after it, then I get an error about importing a package inside the Options section.

So... the question is how to implement document class options while still using `geometry` package? In other words, how to make the above code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\DeclareOption{landscape}{\PassOptionsToPackage{landscape,top=12mm,bottom=12mm,left=15mm,right=15mm}{geometry}}
\DeclareOption{portrait}{\PassOptionsToPackage{portrait,top=15mm,bottom=15mm,left=12mm,right=12mm}{geometry}}
\ExecuteOptions{portrait}
\ProcessOptions

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  a4paper,
  includehead, 
  includefoot,
  headheight=23mm,
  headsep=5mm,
  footskip=1.5em
}
```