# Macro call from options declaring part of the package

Tags: package-writing

I need to call my macro inside `DeclareOption`, but *my macro is defined later* (this is the main condition).

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{MyBook}[2014/12/12]
\DeclareOption{llstyle}{\mymacro}
\ProcessOptions\relax


\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{textcase}

\def\@bookview{
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\renewcommand{\chaptertitlename}{Глава}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace*{-10ex}\Large}
{\titleline[l]{\textls[200]{\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptertitlename}}\ \thechapter}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule[.8pt]}
{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+6pt\relax}
{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
}

\def\mymacro{%
  \@ifclassloaded{book}{\@bookview}{}
  \@ifclassloaded{extbook}{\@bookview}{}
}
\endinput
```

Since, the definition of the macro is made later, this situation causes an error.

Comment: Why not define the macro before declaring it?

Comment: @A.Ellett too easy:-)

Comment: Note that you can `\ProcessOptions` at any point.

Comment: Do you really want to execute the macro when calling the option 'some' or define it? In the first case you will definetely get an error message regarding `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @ A.Ellett "Why not define the macro before declaring it?" because macro require packages, which is call later, besides I had some problems with defining macro before \ProcessOptions set here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/i-get-an-error-when-using-executeoptions-together-with-usepackagegeometry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't given much context, but perhaps

```
\DeclareOption{some}{\AtEndOfPackage{\mymacro}}
```

Comment: @David Carlisle You understand me correctly, thank you.